# How to create USER CONTROL like panel and Header Portion should have fixed design

Tags: asp.net

I want create a user control (Div) like panel and Header Portion should have fixed design to be used in all my web pages. For example, The UserControl can have two DIV or TR with a background design. first DIV has FIxed design and second has to be CONTENT PLACE HOLDER. If it's added to a Page, the UserControl has to allow controls to be added into CONTENT PLACE HOLDER, i.e.  Labels, and TextBoxes . The height of the div should be AUTO. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a custom control approach instead, by creating a class that inherits from panel, like the following:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/panelcurvecontainer.aspx

HTH.